# Why does Netty client connection future.operationComplete get called within the caller thread?

Tags: java, tcp, netty, nonblocking

Below I have demonstrated how I connect using Netty `NioClientSocketChannelFactory`.  Connect returns a future and I can check if 
the connection is successful/failed.

**My understanding is that the connection process is non-locking and so the operationComplete method will be called by netty thread (not within the caller thread) And so the caller thread will exit.**

Most of the time it works this way, on various windows deployments I have.

But on one of the deployments I noticed that when connection fails, the `operationComplete` method is invoked in my caller thread instead of netty thread.
The exception thrown in also caught in the caller thread.  I did not expect this.

In my code, when connection fails, I reattempt a connection (not demonstrated below)...and since it happens in my caller thread, I never return from my connect call, since
the `operationComplete` is called in my caller thread.

What am I doing wrong?  NOTE-I dont have the `future.awaitUninterruptibly` call anywhwere.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
        String host = "localhost";
        int port = 5555;
        ChannelFactory factory = new NioClientSocketChannelFactory(Executors
                        .newCachedThreadPool(), Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
        MyHandler handler = new MyHandler();
        PipelineFactory factory = new PipelineFactory(handler);
        ClientBootstrap bootstrap = new ClientBootstrap(factory);
        ChannelFuture future = bootstrap.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));

        future.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener()
        {
                @Override
                public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception
                {
                    if (future.isSuccess()) {
                        // SUCCESS
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // FAILURE
                    }
                }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not make any assumption in which Thread the actual ChannelFutureListener is notified. Most of the times this will be the IO-Thread (Worker) of Netty but sometimes this also can be the caller Thread.

I still don't understand why it would not "return" for you in that case.

Comment: It wont return, because I try to reconnect right away - Assuming I'm in IO thread :(.  ok I'll change code to remove that assumption. Is this generally true for any concurrency type of implementation where a future is returned? I thought that if a method (anyone in java world) returns a future, the future's listener is always called by another thread.